# Sort list of tuples with Nones and simultaneously sort associated list

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples and list with associated values:

```
unsorted = [(1,3), (None,4), (19,31), (20,32), (8,None), (9,14)]
dists =  [3,None,4,5,None,9]
```

I'd like to sort the 'unsorted' list of tuples so it looks like that:

```
sorted = [(1,3), (None,4), (8,None), (9,14), (19,31), (20,32)]
```

if one element in the tuple is None, take the second one (they are always ascending, so there no situation like `[(8,12),(9,11)]`)

And at the same time I would like to sort associated dists:

```
dists_sorted = [3, None, None, 9, 4, 5]
```

I know I can do this like that:

```
sorted, dists_sorted = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(unsorted, dists))))
```

But I have no idea how to sort tuples with Nones correctly.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried your methods on longer list (it was already sorted):

```
l = [(901, 1), (902, 2), (903, 3), (904, 4), (905, 5), (906, 6), (907, 7), (908, 8), (909, 9), (910, 10), (911, 11), (912, 12), (913, 13), (914, 14), (915, 15), (916, None), (None, 16), (None, 17), (917, 18), (918, 19), (None, 20), (919, 21), (920, 22), (921, 23), (922, 24), (923, 25), (924, 26), (925, 27), (926, 28), (927, 29), (928, 30), (929, 31), (930, 32), (931, 33), (932, None), (933, None), (934, None), (935, None), (None, 34), (None, 35), (None, 36), (None, 37), (None, 38), (None, 39), (936, 40), (937, None), (938, None), (939, 41), (940, 42), (941, 43), (942, 44), (943, 45), (944, 46), (945, 47), (946, 48), (947, 49), (948, 50), (949, 51), (950, 52), (951, 53), (952, 54), (953, 55), (954, 56), (955, 57), (956, 58), (957, 59), (958, 60), (959, 61), (960, 62), (961, 63), (962, 64), (963, 65), (964, 66), (965, 67), (966, 68), (967, 69), (968, 70), (969, 71), (970, 72), (971, 73), (972, 74), (973, None), (974, None), (975, None), (None, 75), (None, 76), (None, 77)]
```

and I got this:

```
out = [(None, 16), (None, 17), (None, 20), (None, 34), (None, 35), (None, 36), (None, 37), (None, 38), (None, 39), (None, 75), (None, 76), (None, 77), (901, 1), (902, 2), (903, 3), (904, 4), (905, 5), (906, 6), (907, 7), (908, 8), (909, 9), (910, 10), (911, 11), (912, 12), (913, 13), (914, 14), (915, 15), (916, None), (917, 18), (918, 19), (919, 21), (920, 22), (921, 23), (922, 24), (923, 25), (924, 26), (925, 27), (926, 28), (927, 29), (928, 30), (929, 31), (930, 32), (931, 33), (932, None), (933, None), (934, None), (935, None), (936, 40), (937, None), (938, None), (939, 41), (940, 42), (941, 43), (942, 44), (943, 45), (944, 46), (945, 47), (946, 48), (947, 49), (948, 50), (949, 51), (950, 52), (951, 53), (952, 54), (953, 55), (954, 56), (955, 57), (956, 58), (957, 59), (958, 60), (959, 61), (960, 62), (961, 63), (962, 64), (963, 65), (964, 66), (965, 67), (966, 68), (967, 69), (968, 70), (969, 71), (970, 72), (971, 73), (972, 74), (973, None), (974, None), (975, None)]
```

So the beginning crashed. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean by *the beginning crashed*?

Comment: It is not sorted: you can find the elements at start of `out` in the original posted list.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Yes, instead of (901,1) at the beginning I got (None,16). Is there any solution for that?

Comment: You go `(None,16)` because in your list there is an element like that in `l`. You wrote that `(None,4)` is less than `(9,14)`. May I understood what you want: if one of two are `None` you want compare the seconds elements of the tuple.... I'll fix my answer.

Comment: You MUST be more clear: that not a valid rule to do sort. What about compare `(None, 4)` and `(8, None)`?

Comment: Why `(None, 16)` is bigger than `(916, None)` and lesser than `(932, None)`? That is not a sort rule.

Comment: I see... I omitted this fact. I'll try to figure out how to solve this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` parameter can help you to solve it. Anyway take a look to [sorted mini HOWTO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sorting_Mini-HOW_TO). Is a very good resource.

```
>>> unsorted = [(1,3), (None,4), (19,31), (20,32), (8,None), (9,14)]
>>> sorted(unsorted, key=lambda x:x[0] if x[0] is not None else x[1])
[(1, 3), (None, 4), (8, None), (9, 14), (19, 31), (20, 32)]
```

**[EDIT]**
Based on above comments you want a rule like that `(a,b)` is less `(c,d)` if and only is:

- if `c` and `d` is not `None` `c<d`
- if `c` or `d` is None `a<b`

... But that is not a sort rule. At the end of your example you say that `l` is sorted but you can find `(916, None)<(None, 16)<(932, None)`: there is no rule to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sorted with a proper `key` :

```
>>> sorted(unsorted,key= lambda x: x[0] if x[0] else x[1])
[(1, 3), (None, 4), (8, None), (9, 14), (19, 31), (20, 32)]
```

as says in comment if may you have zero , use `is not None` for check the `None` :

```
>>> sorted(unsorted,key= lambda x: x[0] if x[0] is not None else x[1])
[(1, 3), (None, 4), (8, None), (9, 14), (19, 31), (20, 32)]
```

Comment: I'd use `is not None` because there may be zeros in there.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes its more efficient but , i do it for this case !

Answer (score 1):

One way (the easier to understand) would be:

```
def f(e):
    if e[0] is None:
        return e[1]
    return e[0]

print sorted(unsorted, key = f)
```

The simplified way, using `lambda` is:

```
print sorted(unsorted, lambda e: e[1] if e[0] is None else e[0])
```

Both lead to the same result.

**Edit:**

To match with what you have done, you can make a little modification to the function `f`:

```
def f(e):
    if e[0][0] is None:
        return e[0][1]
    return e[0][0]

sorted1, dists_sorted = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(unsorted, dists), key = f)))

>>> 
[(1, 3), (None, 4), (8, None), (9, 14), (19, 31), (20, 32)]
[3, None, None, 9, 4, 5]
```

Note that `e[0]` will be the item of `unsorted`, and `e[1]` the corresponding in `dists`.